# How to implement a partial SSL handshake to test arbitrary cipher suites?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tls1.2, sslsocketfactory

The "server" needs to be tested to make sure it does not include a specific cipher suite, which sometimes, despite our developer's best intentions, still occasionally makes it into the server.

However:

- We cannot use an online service to test the server, because the server is not on the internet
- We cannot use a library because the devices running the tests are using a special JDK and external libraries do not compile
- We cannot use locally-installed tools because the runtime is specific and not linux/windows compatible

(= we have to roll our own, using standard Java 8)

Furthermore, we are not interested to test just the cipher suites that the test client has installed but "any" cipher suite that will be provided as arbitrary text.

I found online ([OpenSSL Cookbook by Ivan Ristić](https://www.feistyduck.com/books/openssl-cookbook/)):

> For SSL Labs, I resorted to using partial handshakes for this purpose, with a custom client that pretends to support arbitrary suites. It actually can’t negotiate even a single suite, but just proposing to negotiate is enough for servers to tell you if they support a suite or not. Not only can you test all the suites this way, but you can also do it very efficiently.

This custom client sounds ideal for our purposes now and will be useful for similar SSL tests in the future - but I don't know what a "partial handshake" or "propose to negotiate" looks like in Java-8's SSL Sockets code.
My best effort is the following:

```
String[] enabledSuites = {"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"};
mySocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(enabledSuites);
mySocket.startHandshake();
```

The suite mentioned above works, because the client has it and the server allows it.
However, when I try "MY_SUITE", the code stops at `setEnabledCipherSuites()` with: `Unsupported CipherSuite: MY_SUITE`
Which, to me, means the client didn't even try this, because it's not part of the list shown when doing `getSupportedCipherSuites()`

So, can a partial handshake be even implemented in Java 8 (without rewriting all the extra code that's on top of Socket)?

Comment: What do you call a partial handshake ? All handshakes start with a Client Hello message that suggest one or more cipher suites and this message has no property that could be partial or full. Besides, each Java version doesn't cover all SSL possibilities and you could instead rely on [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) (which doesn't cover everything but still cover more than Java).

Comment: that's my question(s) :) What is the minimal handshake that'll let me know if the server accepts the Cipher Suite? As for Java not covering all SSL possibilities - that's exactly why I need to write a PartialHandshaker that can accept an arbitrary (=not necessarily in the java client) Cipher Suite. According to the info I found, it's not only possible, but it's a fast way to just TEST if the server may accept insecure connections

Comment: Your code is correct for testing a single Cipher, if it is not accepted by the server an [SSLHandshakeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLHandshakeException.html) will be raised informing you that you could not go further. It isn't a partial handshake, but a minimal thing. Trying a cipher not covered by your Java version will raise the Exception you showed, hence the limits of Java for this purpose.

Comment: it will be hacked. If I got SSLv2, I will get this one too ;)

Comment: Java does not support such partial handshakes in its SSL/TLS api. I see no reason why you even need to perform a partial handshake anyway, just attempt to perform a regular complete handshake with each ciphersuite and see if it succeeds. SSLabs is testing thousands of servers per day, so performance tweaks are critical. Not so for your requirements.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk More interesting than performance is the ability to use more than the 44 suites on board the typical Java distribution. There are about 500 of them and the ones they put with java are the "good" ones anyway... Remember this is a testing application.

Comment: That's a good point, and a reason you may not want to use the Java SSL/TLS api. There is a bouncycastle SSL/TLS Java library, it's open source so you can modify it for your needs and perhaps save yourself a lot of coding. I also seem to recall something like source code for the SSLabs tester on github. This was many years ago and I haven't really been tracking it, and my memory is not what it used to be ...

Comment: yes! I will grab the bouncycastle code and make it compile under our special machines. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in this project which I think includes all the code you might want for this type of thing:

```
https://github.com/ChristopherSchultz/ssltest
```

When you say a "partial handshake" I think what you mean is that you want to probe the server for support for a specific protocol/cipher suite pair (or group, etc.). You can use an `SSLSocket` for this purpose, and you don't need to make e.g. an HTTPS connection and actually perform a transaction.

In order to get anything but the JVM default protocols and ciphers, you'll need to supply your own `SSLSocketFactory` which customizes an `SSLSocket` as it's being created / connected. That code is in the `CustomSSLSocketFactory` class in the above project, and of course there is code in there showing how to use it.

Remember that the JVM has a group of cipher suites and protocols that have been implemented, but many of them have been disabled over the years and you may have to take steps to re-enable them. The code in this project sets system properties immediately after startup in order to remove as many restrictions as possible. That may not be possible (or advisable!) in your environment because you don't want to allow "regular code" to use these insecure algorithms and protocols.